# Gluon Mobile app is terribly slow on iPhone Sumulator

Tags: ios, performance, ios-simulator, gluon

Simple "default" Gluon Mobile app (Single View project, the one generated via New Project) runs terribly slow on iPhone simulator on my macbook. If I add a couple of controls and views - it almost hangs and loads the CPU too much (just by being open in Simulator it turns my macbook into a frying pan).
But the same app runs perfectly smooth on Windows, MacOS and Android device.
IDE: IntelliJ Idea 2018.1, gradle task "launchIphoneSimulator".

Any ideas why is that so? Does anybody have the same performance issues with Gluon Mobile on iPhone Simulator?

Comment: While the simulator is notably slower than the real device (have you tried it?), I wouldn't say "terribly" slower.  It will depend of course on your machine. Note that either way the first time you launch the task the AOT compiler will go through a very long (more than 20 minutes) and intense process to compile all the Java classes. Since this goes to cache, the next run will work fine in nearly a minute. Just in case, make sure you increase memory settings in your gradle.properties file: `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms256m -Xmx4096m -Xss2m`.

Comment: The app on a real device works fine. And it literally takes a few seconds to react to a mouse click or keyboard input while on simulator. It doesn't matter if it is a first launch or not. It never takes 20 minutes to compile, only about a minute - it is a really "hello-world" app after all.I will play with VM memory settings though.

Comment: The very first launch you make to the simulator or to a device will take around 20 minutes because of the AOT compiler. Then you will have mostly everything compiled in cache, so every new launch will take around 1 minute. If you have a device, I don't see any advantage of using the simulator (most of the sensors you have on the device won't work on it).

Comment: Please, see my previous comment: it **never** takes 20 minutes to compile, even at the first launch. So I'm pretty sure the problem is not in hardware's resources. Unfortunately, using the device isn't always convenient, and if the framework has problems running on simulator, it may indicate further issues. Playing with JVM memory settings had no effect.

Comment: The fact that you can run on desktop the same application with same code base helps fast development and testing, before deploying to devices. If you want to test specific features (like native services implementations) you have to test on a device anyway. In my case, I hardly use the simulator... But if I have to, it is not as bad as you have described.

Comment: Actually, I've already ran into some os-specific problems, e.g. when receiving http GET response as utf-8 string via Gluon's RestClient it needs to be decoded to windows-1251 when running on Windows desktop to get correct localized symbols (cyrillic in my case), but no decoding is required on macOS, iOS (simulator) and Android. So yes, you're right - the device is needed anyway, but I was hoping to be able to develop os-independent logic and UI on simulator... Turns out, that's not the case.

Comment: @Oleg But why do you want "to develop os-independent logic and UI on simulator"? Isn't it much easier to do that directly on your development desktop and neither on the simulator nor the device? I never use the simulator. I either use the desktop or a device.

Comment: @mipa Well, the simulator exactly runs on my development desktop/laptop, so I can, for example, take screenshots when needed in one click or work with my laptop anywhere without being tangled in wires and connected devices. It is a matter of convenience, I mentioned that earlier. But to be honest, I've never ran into performance issues like this with simulator on other cross-platform frameworks (e.g. Intel's MOE or JS-based ReactNative) - that what's bugging me in the first place.

Comment: @Oleg I think you misunderstood me. Of course is your simulator also running on your desktop/laptop. I just wanted to point out that with gluon mobile you can also run your app natively on the desktop (without any simulator) which makes things much faster and more practical for debugging than any simulator.

Comment: @mipa Sure. Moreover, I didn't find a way to debug gluon mobile application while running on device (is it possible at all? I mean the usual way, using IDE?). But I've already ran into some situations where the code which runs smoothly on desktop platform will cause troubles on mobile, and it is not always obvious...